# What is wrong with the following code? Iterator type does not work in a template function?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
template<typename Container>
void remove(Container &list){
    typename Container::iterator iter;
    iter = list.begin();

    while( iter != list.end()){
            iter = list.erase( iter);
            if( iter ! = list.end())
                    iter++;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::list<int> chess;
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int n=0; n<100; n++){
            chess.push_back(n);
            v.push_back(n);
    }
    remove(chess);
    remove(v);
    std::cout<<chess.back()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<v.back()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> [Error] expected ')' before '!' token
>
> [Error] could not convert 'iter' from 'std::list::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator}' to 'bool'
>
> [Error] could not convert 'iter' from 'std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' to 'bool'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if( iter ! = list.end())
```

should be

```
        if( iter != list.end()) // No space between ! and =
```

Comment: first come first serve.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( iter ! = list.end())
```

should be

```
if( iter != list.end())
```

Note the extra space between `!` and `=` in your code.

My advice for the future: Handle compiler error in the order they appear in. Often enough, fixing the first one will make some of the others go away.